# trig proof help please, my work is attached

Tags: trigonometry

I worked on both sides and thought i would end up with the original equation? my work is attached.

[image]

Comment: thank you gentlemen, i see it quite clearly now. i appreciate your time

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{ \sec x }{ \sec x -\tan x }=\frac{ \sec x }{ \sec x -\tan x }\times\frac{ \sec x +\tan x}{ \sec x +\tan x } =\frac{ \sec x(\sec x+ \tan x) }{ \sec ^2x -\tan^2 x }=\frac{ \sec x(\sec x+ \tan x) }{ 1 }$$

Comment: I don't know why my latex do not work ! but i suggest multiply left side by (sec x+tan x)/(sec x+tan x) , simplify ,as easy as you think ,  you will see the answer

Comment: When using latex you should encode it between two dollar signs "$"..And for trigonometric ratios like sin, cos etc you should put a "\" slash before it so it comes out like above. @khosrotash. You can read more here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: thank you gentlemen, i see it quite clearly now. i appreciate your time

Answer (score 2):

On your third line you lost parentheses.

$\dfrac{\sec x}{\sec x - \tan x} = \sec^2 x + \sec x \tan x$

$ \iff \dfrac{\sec x}{\sec x - \tan x} = \sec x[\sec x + \tan x] 
$

$\iff \dfrac{1}{\sec x - \tan x} = \sec x + \tan x $

$\iff 1 = \sec^2 x - \tan^2 x $

Comment: thank you gentlemen, i see it quite clearly now. i appreciate your time

Answer (score 2):

On the second line you worked on both sides of the equation. After that you only worked on the right-hand side.
So, you could just work on the right-hand side completely and end up like the left-hand side. So, on step 2 instead of working on both sides, just multiply the right side by (secx - tanx) and also multiply the right side by one over (secx - tanx). Then do exactly what you have done and at the last step multiply what you have done times the factor one over (secx - tanx) which has been waiting all this time on the right of the right-hand side.
Convert the 1/cosx  to the equivilent secx and multiply times the 1/(secx - tanx) to get the same as the left-hand side.

Comment: thank you gentlemen, i see it quite clearly now. i appreciate your time